# Issue with CakePHP model validationErrors property

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.1

I am using CakePHP 2.1.3 for one of my project, I want model validation errors to be returned in JSON format via controller, when I try to access validation errors via CakePHP's model property validationErrors it returns valid errors array when primary and all other associated models has validation errors. But when primary model is valid and associated models has validation errors it results invalid validation errors array. Below is an example:

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
    if ($this->PrimaryModel->saveAll($this->request->data, array('validate' => 'first'))) {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
    } else {
        $errors=array();
        $tablesToModels=$this->PrimaryModel->tableToModel; //List of table names included in the model description. Used for associations.
        foreach($tablesToModels as $tabel => $model) {
            $errors[$model]=$this->{$model}->validationErrors;
        }
        pr($errors);
        //echo json_encode(array('errors' => $errors));
    }
    exit;
}
```

The Above code results following output if primary and associated models has validation errors:

```
Array
(
    [PrimaryModel] => Array
        (
            [field1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => notempty
                )

        )

    [AssociatedModel] => Array
        (
            [field1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => notempty
                )

            [field2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => notempty
                )

        )
)
```

And when all fields are filled in primary model, or primary model has no validation errors it results following errors array:

```
Array
(
    [PrimaryModel] => Array
        (
            [AssociatedModel] => Array
                (
                    [field1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => notempty
                        )

                    [field2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => notempty
                        )

                )

        )

    [AssociatedModel] => Array
        (
            [field1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => notempty
                )

            [field2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => notempty
                )

        )

)
```

I don't know why this is happening and where I am doing anything wrong?

Here is an edit form code incase you guys need it to sort it out:

```
<php
    echo $this->Form->input('PrimaryModel.field1');
    echo $this->Form->input('PrimaryModel.field2');
    echo $this->Form->input('PrimaryModel.field3');
    echo $this->Form->input('PrimaryModel.field4');
    echo $this->Form->input('AssociatedModel.field1');
    echo $this->Form->input('AssociatedModel.field2');
    echo $this->Form->input('AssociatedModel.field3');
    echo $this->Form->input('PrimaryModel.field5');
?>
```

Thank you all in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The controller generally constructs the `$validationErrors` property when it renders the action. Instead of echoing json directly from the controller, you should use a json view. Let the view handle the display logic, in this case, displaying the results as json instead of regular html.

Add the extension to your routes file:

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

Then create a view in `/View/Controller/json/action.ctp` replacing 'controller' and 'action' with your controller and action name. The view will look like this:

```
echo json_encode($this->validationErrors);
```

You will also need to create a json layout in `/View/Layouts/json/default.ctp`.

```
echo $content_for_layout;
```

And you access it like a normal action, but using the `.json` extension, like `http://example.com/controller/action.json`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but your reply is not much useful for me as I am looking to find solution for cakephp errors array but you are telling me how to render json :(

Comment: This method would solve your issues because you need to let Cake finish merging the validation errors. Did you try it?

Comment: jeremy I have followed your given steps, nothing changed. When I submit form it display complete html with forms & errors. I want to get only errors in json format.

Comment: What kind of HTML errors? If it's directing you to an error page (like 404), that's a different story. You can make a json view for that error page as well.